# WCF Data Service Update returns 401- Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have a WCF data service and I am trying to use the UpdateObject method on the DataServiceContext client.  When I call the SaveChanges method, I get the following error page:

> **Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials**
>   *You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.*

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can fix this?  I found [this](http://www.devcow.com/blogs/adnrg/archive/2010/07/20/debugging-a-wcf-data-services-problem.aspx), which would theoretically fix the problem, but setting this disk access is not a realistic solution for a production service.  Keep in mind, when running this WCF Data service on my local machine, it works just fine.  The C# code for my call is below:

```
        public override void SetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyValueCollection collection)
    {
        var userName = ( string ) context[ "UserName" ];
        var isAuthenticated = ( bool ) context[ "IsAuthenticated" ];
        if (userName != null && userName.Length >= 1 && collection.Count >= 1)
        {
            var allNames = string.Empty;
            var allValues = string.Empty;
            byte[] buf = null;
            PrepareDataForSaving( ref allNames, ref allValues, ref buf, true, collection, isAuthenticated );
            if (allNames.Length != 0)
            {
                var client = GetDataContext( );
                var profile = client.ProfileViews.Where(p => p.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();
                if (profile == null)
                {
                   profile = new ProfileView() { UserName = userName };
                    client.AddToProfileViews(profile);
                }
                profile.PropertyNames = allNames;
                profile.PropertyValuesString = allValues;
                profile.PropertyValuesBinary = buf;
                profile.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;


                client.UpdateObject(profile);
                client.SaveChanges( );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similiar issue with a Silverlight application that was using WCF Data Services.   The users could view data in the application---SELECTS from the database were functioning---but they were receiving the same "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied du to invalid credentials." you are describing when they attempted to save changes to the database (i.e., at the point when SaveChanges was executed in code).   The underlying problem ended up being a permissions issue with the IIS application folder itself.  To fix, we had to grant the Application Pool being used by the WCF service Write permissions to the folder.

1. Go to IIS and right click on the virtual directory containing the WCF service and choose Manage Application -> Advanced Settings....  Make note of the Application Pool name.
2. Within same right-click menu, choose Edit Permissions.....  On Security tab, check group and user names.
3. If the name of the Application Pool is missing.  Add it using the name format "IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationPoolName".  See this helpful link:  http://www.bluevalleytech.com/techtalk/blog/assigning-ntfs-folder-permission-to-iis7-application-pools/
4. Make sure MyApplicationPoolName has Write permissions (we actually gave it Full control)

Comment: just a note - make sure you click 'Locations' and check off the machine name. if you don't, it will not find IIS APPPOOL\'AppPoolName' user. I had a heck of a time figuring this one out :D. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had Windows authentication with impersonation using kerberos (useAppPoolCredentials=true) on a WCF Data Service hosted on IIS 7.5. The weird thing was that I could successfully select and insert data, but when I tried to update I got a 401.3 access denied error. The solution was to give the AD group specified in the web config (myRole):

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="myRole"/>  
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Read and write access to the application folder like Dan Sabin said . The error message was:

Error message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the Web server's administrator to give you access